# how to read the WIFI condition (On or Off) on Windows-mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How to read the WIFI condition (On or Off) on Windows-mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered you already in the Windows Mobile MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/7268b0a9-586c-4289-9365-af92fe9fce4a

But, you can use the State and Notification Broker API with the SN_WIFISTATEPOWERON_* options or use NDIS to request power change notifications with NDISUIO_NOTIFICATION_DEVICE_POWER_* options.

I describe them in depth and with example code in: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/RadioPower.aspx

-PaulH